# Stats gone wild

Tags: bug, status-completed

What happened to our stats?

[image]

They are surely wrong but what is the reason for it?

Comment: This is a known bug. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234383/224428. This was probably caused by the database issues that happened 2-3 days ago that caused some site outages.

Comment: Don't blame the statistics; just BE MORE AVID. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @shenshin points out this issue has affected Area51 for a couple of days at least. I noticed yesterday it said 0 questions per day.  There is a little more about the issue in this Meta-Stackexchange post:

[Who borked the Area 51 stats?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234383/162011)